# design a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

Im trying to make a fancy presentation with beamer and i'd like to put some diagram like this
[image]

There is some software with rulers in the preview pdf or something like this to desing the beamer presentation?

I'm used to work with tikz, but i dont really where is the correct position without any ruler

Comment: I'm not understanding what parts of your image you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few quick settings to give you a starting point:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{magpie}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=}
\setbeamertemplate{background}[grid][color=gray,step=3mm]

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=orange}

\tikzset{
  decoration={random steps,segment length=2mm,amplitude=0.6pt}
}

\tcbset{
  enhanced,
  interior empty,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-0.18cm,xshift=-0.5mm},
  boxed title style={
    interior empty,
    tikz={rotate=4,transform shape},
    frame code={
      \draw[decorate,draw=beamer@tcb@titlebg,fill=beamer@tcb@titlebg!30!bg] (frame.south west) rectangle (frame.north east);
    }
  },
  frame code={
    \draw[decorate,draw=beamer@tcb@titlebg,fill=beamer@tcb@titlebg!30!bg] (frame.north east) rectangle (frame.south west);
  },
}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\hskip-1cm\color{orange}\rule{4cm}{2pt}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frametitle}
    Text\footnote{Footnote text}
  
  \begin{block}{Block Title}
  content...
  \end{block}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, to do this i set a grid as background whit 0.5cm separation. And i'm using this kind of frames:

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
    %\fill[white,opacity=.25] (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);%this is just to see where i can put something
    %\node[text=white] at (1cm,9.2cm) ;
    \draw[-,line width=2pt ,amarillo] (0cm,8.5cm) to node[above,white] {\LARGE\ Problem:} (2.5cm,8.5cm);
    \node at (\the\paperwidth*0.5,7cm) {Este es el problema};
    \fill[morado] (0.5,3cm) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,4.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Is this actually supposed to be an edit to the original question?

Comment: Using tikz to add a background grid sounds a bit overkill. Beamer has a build in function for this: `\setbeamertemplate{background}[grid][color=lightgray,step=3mm]`